# realcompact space

Tags: gn.general-topology

I want to study [realcompact spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realcompact_space) but I can't find the best book or journal for it, and I really need to.

(sorry I don't write English very well)

Comment: I don't know much about the subject, but the Gillman and Jerison "Rings of continuous functions" is a good book in general.

Comment: I agree strongly with that recommendation.

Comment: The standard reference is the book on Hewitt-Nachbin spaces by Weir (the title is another alibi of realcompact spaces).

Comment: Try Engelking's "General topology" (they are named "Hewitt spaces" therein).

Comment: All of references in these comments are useful. Particularly Gilman jerison.